# After exploiting a router using routersploit, what do you have control of?

Tags: exploit, router

I've seen the routersploit program on Github. It's a similar program to metasploit in a way that it exploits vulnerabilities in network devices (or just routers I think. Not too sure). I see that I targets most routers and exploits their vulnerabilities, but I don't understand a few things. What do you get out of exploiting a router and what do you have control of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, a router is a computer, so like any other computer, you get the ability to use its resources for your own purposes: processing power for cryptomining, use of its networking resources for DDoS attacks or spamming.

Secondly, a router sits across the network path of any computers on its network, so it provides the ability to man in the middle attack all network traffic from those computers. This allows you to attempt to steal data for identify theft and other forms of financial fraud.

Thirdly, in more targeted attacks, a router can serve as a jumping off point within the network of the target, allowing attacks onto other systems that may bypass firewalls due to the traffics origin from within the network. If the router appliance is also the firewall, exploiting the router may allow the attacker to completely ignore the firewall.

Comment: So is it also possible to connect to a specific device connected to the network, such as a computer, and take control of it? Can you generate a reverse shell in some way too? Also, when you exploit the router, how do you get the wifi password?

Comment: @MatthewSchell It depends on the network, but if you have control of the router, then you can attempt exploits against any devices on the network without worrying about the firewall on the router. But you still have to attack any defences that the computer it self has. As for wifi, if the router you take over has wifi, you have complete control over the wifi AP, and can read out and/or modify the key.

Comment: And those defenses would be things like an Anti Virus or Full Disk Encryption?

Comment: @MatthewSchell Anti virus and any built in firewall. Disk encryption isn't really relevant for attacks against live systems.

Comment: One last thing. What are ways to prevent your router from getting exploited. Also, do the techniques to protect it vary from different router companies?

Comment: @MatthewSchell the only way is to keep it up to date, or replace it if the vendor is not providing updates. It also helps to disable remote access.

Comment: remote access to what? you mean to 192.168.1.1 in the search bar?